# C++ Error message " I was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void fun1 (int a [], int length)
{int i;
for (i = 0; i<length; i++)
    a[i] = a[i] =a[i];
length = 2 * length;
return; }

int main()
{int b[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
fun1 (b, b[1]);
for (i = 0; i<5; i++) // <-- ERROR HERE!
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
return 0; }
```

> In function 'int main()':
> [Error] 'i' was not declared in this scope

I have this error popping out, and I don't know what the solution is for it.

Comment: Please post your code/errors as text, not images.  For people that can't see images for one reason or another your question is unanswerable.  We also can't copy the text from images, which stops us from being able to debug your code, i.e., help you.

Comment: Do you know how to declare a variable?  Would you agree that `i` was not declared as any kind of variable in the scope of `main`?

Comment: FYI, `a[i] = a[i] =a[i];` is effectively a no-op, since the result is the same as the input. Perhaps you meant something more like `a[i] = i;` instead? Also, the result of `length = 2 * length;` is being thrown away immediately afterwards, effectively making this a no-op, too. Also, in `fun1 (b, b[1]);`, `b[1]` is `3`, so you are telling `fun1()` that `a[]` has 3 elements, but it actually as 5 elements. Are you sure this is what you really want? This whole code makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

`fun1()` is declaring `i` as a local variable:

```c
void fun1 (int a [], int length)
{int i; // <-- HERE
for (i = 0; i<length; i++)
    a[i] = a[i] =a[i];
length = 2 * length;
return; }
```

Local variables inside of a function are not accessible to other functions, unless they are passed around explicitly.  So, in this case, `main()` has no access to `i` in `fun1()` (nor should it).

The error you are seeing is simply because `main()` is trying to use its own `i` without declaring it first.  You can't use something before it has been declared. So, you just need to add that declaration, eg:

```c
int main()
{int b[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int i; // <-- ADD THIS!
fun1 (b, b[1]);
for (i = 0; i<5; i++) // <-- OK NOW!
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
return 0; }
```

Alternatively, you should get in the habit of declaring a loop's counter variable inside the loop declaration itself, eg:

```c
void fun1 (int a [], int length)
{for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) // <-- OK!
    a[i] = a[i] =a[i];
length = 2 * length;
return; }

int main()
{int b[5] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
fun1 (b, b[1]);
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) // <-- OK, TOO!
    printf("%d ", b[i]);
return 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  for (int i=0;i<length;i++)
```

Comment: Still not working

Comment: @SippinSizzurp [It works fine for me](https://ideone.com/2IX4cF)

Comment: @SippinSizzurp Yes it is. [See for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/n44153Pv8)

Comment: Maybe one line of explanation wouldn't hurt.

Comment: "not working" is not a sufficient problem description to give anyone, in the hopes of being offered a solution.

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.